# dynamicall create a table with checkboxes in rails as part of a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, checkbox

I need to create a form where users can upload multiple files and then check off certain attributes before sending the files off. Each file input field should be displayed in a table, along with the checkboxes for each file input field.

However, I don't know ahead of time how many entries in the table there are. It depends on the number of files in a certain folder, and that changes.

So the code I have to create the table and form is:

```
<% counter = 0 %>
<%= simple_form_for(@myResource, :as => :myResource, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
    <table>
        <% @filesInFolder.each do |file| %>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%= // Need checkboxes here %>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <% counter = counter+1 %>
        <% end %>
    </table>
<% end %>
```

Now I can easily put the checkboxes and input fields using 'check_box_tag' and 'file_field_tag'. However, I am not sure how to access them on the other side, since I'm used to doing 'f.check_box' and 'f.file_field'. I don't know how to use 'f.check_box' in this case since I have to give them the names ahead of time

```
f.check_box :input_checkbox1 ...
```

And I need to give them dynamic names based on how many of these I create, so with 'check_box_tag' I can go

```
check_box_tag "checkBox#{counter}"
```

So how do I make checkboxes I can easily access with a controller for a form, but create as many as I need and name them dynamically?

EDIT: To clarify, @fileInFolder is collection of file names, but not the files I want uploaded. Let's say I have 5 files in that folder, then I want that interface 5 times so that users can check off certain options and upload SUPPLEMENTARY files to those already in the folder.
Also, uploading the files would create several records, but one per each file uploaded, not per each file in the folder. So if I have 5 files in the folder, and the user only checks off boxes for 3 of them, I will create 3 new records

Comment: What kind of models do you have? You probably need to take a look at nested forms, because basically you have to create a instantiation of the model to which you would like to save for each file. Because sending the request to the controller will not create 1 record, but multiple records I guess. Are those records by themselves related to one base record in another model? Without understanding better what you'd like to achieve this is a hard one to answer.

Comment: Yep, how you intend to store them in the database, might make your view-code easier (e.g. using nested-forms). But, please clarify `@filesInFolder` --> are these files on the server? So in that case a user is not actually "uploading" files, but selecting already uploaded files, or, do you want to actually read a folder from the user's computer (which a browser/javascript imho is not able to do, unless you use java applet or flash) --in that case: why not just let the user upload multiple files instead?

Comment: Edit added to clarify @filesInFolder, but it's basically an array of filenames

Answer (score -1):

To count like you want do this thing:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@myResource, :as => :myResource, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
    <table>
        <% @filesInFolder.each_with_index do |file, index| %>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%= f.check_box "check-box-#{index}", file.whatever %>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>
    </table>
<% end %>
```

Of course, your variable @filesInFolder must be a selecton from DB

Comment: it's giving me `undefined method 'check-box-0' for #<MyResource:0x007f9a756dff80">`. That's the main issue I have with using `check_box` instead of `check_box_tag`

Comment: O yah! Sorry. Really if you use constraction like this <%= f.check_box :field, file.whatever %>, name of field must be reference to field in you model

Comment: yeah I know, that IS the problem I am facing. Are `f.check_box` and `check_box_tag` (without the `f.`) equivalent?

Comment: No, they not. When you use f.checkbox :field_name, you :field_name its a reference to field in database. And check_box_tag just a form tag without this references